# User's username not appearing on React navigation bar

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React to create a Navbar component for your website. The Navbar should display the user's username, the user is logged in, and provide links to various pages on the website. I am using localStorage to store the user's data, and axios to make API requests. However, i am encountering an issue where the user's username is not appearing on the Navbar.

```js
function NavbarScroll() {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

function handleLogout() {

axios.post(`${API_URL}/logout`)
    .then(response = {
//Remove the user data from localStorage and set user state to null
localStorage.removeItem('user');
setUser(null);

//Navigate to the home page after logging out
navigate('/');
    })
    .catch(error = {
console.error(error);
    });
}

useEffect(() = {
const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log('userData:', userData); // add this line to verify the userData value
if (userData !== null) {
setUser(userData);
    }
console.log('user:', user);
[]);

return (

<Nav.Link>{user && <span>Welcome, {user.username}</span>}</Nav.Link>

);}export default NavbarScroll;
```

Comment: does `console.log('userData:', userData);` inside useEffect write the expected data to the console?

Comment: Yes, console.log('userData:', userData). write the expected data to the console if the userData exists in localStorage. userData: 
Object
message
: 
"Login successful"
user
: 
{id: 5, username: 'monsefadmin', email: 'monsef@admin.com', email_verified_at: null, role: 'admin', …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: So your `userData` object is `{ message: ..., user: ... }`? Then if you use `setUser(userData)`, the `user` object in your state won't have a `username` property but only `user.message` and `user.user` ... So either use `setUser(userData.user)` or use `{user.user.username}` in your `Nav.Link` ...

Comment: Or refactor at saving your userobject to localStorage to save only the `user` object instead of the whole api response ...

Comment: thank you so much! you solved my error.